# why $\int \frac{1}{1+\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx = \ln\left | \tan(\frac{x}{2})+1 \right |+const.$?

Tags: calculus, integration

This is how I solve $$\int \frac{1}{1+\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$$, but I got the wrong answer, and the correct answer is $$\ln\left | \tan(\frac{x}{2})+1 \right |+\text{const}.$$

How to solve this？

[image]

Comment: Your answer is correct. Your answer is equal to $\ln (\tan \frac{x}{2} + 1 ) + \ln 2 + const$, which is the same set of antiderivatives as the answer you quote at the beginning, since the constant is arbitrary.

Comment: To comment on your previous deleted question. I meant "measure" as in "measure theory". That might be what you want.

Comment: @ZacharySelk Thank you. I am trying to define the previous deleted question better. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two answers are "the same" since $\log(2\tan(x/2)+2)=\log 2+\log(\tan(x/2)+1$. The rest is taken care of by the arbitrary constant of integration.

**Remark:** There are slightly easier ways to handle this integral. Using the double-angle formulas for sine and cosine, we find that we want to integrate
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)+\cos^2(x/2)}.$$
Divide top and bottom by $\cos^2(x/2)$. We find that we want to integrate
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\sec^2(x/2)}{1+\tan(x/2)}.$$
Now make the substitution $u=1+\tan(x/2)$.

Answer (score 3):

When you substitute $\frac{du}{dx}$ in for $\sec^2\frac{x}{2}$, you forgot about the $\frac{1}{2}$. You needed to sub in $2\frac{du}{dx}$.

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align}
\sin x &= \frac{2\tan(x/2)}{1 + \tan(x/2)} \\
\cos x &= \frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+ \tan^2x} \\
1+\sin x+\cos x &= \frac{2 + 2\tan(x/2)}{1+\tan(x/2)} \\
I &= \int\frac{dx}{1+\sin x+\cos x} \\
&= \int\frac{\sec(x/2)}{2+\tan(x/2)} dx
\end{align}

Let $z=\tan(x/2)$, then $dz=\frac12\sec(x/2)dx$ and
\begin{align}
I &= \int \frac22 \frac{dz}{1+z} \\
&= \log|z+1| +c \\
&= \log(\tan(x/2)+1) + c
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).